# What happens if two dependent java services have different 'probability' value?

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I have two services(S1, S2) in a chain. I call with CURL(or Postman) S1, and S1 sends request to S2.
S1 has -  spring.sleuth.sampler.probability: 0.1
S2 has -   spring.sleuth.sampler.probability: 0.5

I don't understand how the system will behave.

**If i send 100 requests:**

1. S1 will export to zipkin 100 * 0.1 = 10 requests, and S2 will export 10 * 0.5 = 5 requests?

or

2. S1 will export to zipkin 100 * 0.1 = 10 requests, and S2 will export 100 * 0.5 = 50 requests?

or

3. S1 and S2 will export to zipkin 0.1 * 0.5 * 100 =  5 requests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If S1 sends a request to S2 it's the S1 that sets the sampler value and S2 just continues the result. In other words S1 will export to zipkin 100 * 0.1 = 10 requests, and S2 will export 100 * 0.1 = 10 requests. S1 makes a decision and S2 will continue it.

Comment: In the other words, the property spring.sleuth.sampler.probability in S2 service is ignored. Thank you!

Comment: If S2 doesn't get any requests then yes it is. Can we mark this as answered?